# Fork neither failing nor loading program specified?

Tags: c, process, fork

Running into strange error I'm totally failing to troubleshoot. I have a fork which loads an executable I know exists, but none of the code executes. It does not fail, which I know because I check exactly that, so I'm really baffled bu what's going on. Here is the code of the two processes:
Process 1(PipeC.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){  
    int fd[2], B, C, D, numberRead, i, pipeReturn;
    char *arg[3];
    char charsRead [10000], fdNumberAsString[256];

    pipeReturn = pipe(fd);
        if(pipeReturn < 0){ printf("error creating pipe"); return;}
    sprintf(fdNumberAsString, "%d", fd[0]);
    arg[0] = fdNumberAsString;
            //printf("%d\n", fdNumberAsString);
    sprintf(fdNumberAsString, "%d", fd[1]);
            //printf("%d\n", fdNumberAsString);
    arg[1] = fdNumberAsString;
    arg[2] = NULL;

    printf("fd[0] = string: %s    int: %d\n", arg[0], arg[0]);
    printf("fd[1] = string: %s    int: %d\n", arg[1], arg[1]);

    //printf("fd[0] = %d, fd[1] = %d\n", fd[0], fd[1]);

    B = fork();
    if(B == 0){
        execv("PipeW1", arg);
        printf("Fork failed"); 
        exit(1);
    }
    

    close(fd[1]);

    numberRead = read(fd[0], charsRead, 5);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)printf("%c ", charsRead[numberRead]);
    
    exit(0);
}
```

Process Two (PipeW1.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int x, char** args){ 
    printf("here");
    int fd[2], pipeReturn;
    char num[256];
    fd[0] = atoi(*args);
    
    fd[1] = atoi(*(args+1));

    printf("fd[0] = string: %s    int: %d\n", fd[0], fd[0]);
    printf("fd[1] = string: %s    int: %d\n", fd[1], fd[1]);

    close(fd[0]);
    write(fd[1], "12345", 5);

    exit(0);
}
```

The second process was even printing earlier... Very confused as I said, any ideas?

edit: output:

```
[myname@myschool Lab6]$ PipeC
PipeC - fd[0] = string: 4    int: -737006768
PipeC - fd[1] = string: 4    int: -737006768
here
     [myname@myschool Lab6]$
```

Comment: We don't need a proof, we trust you, it's enough to tell us that you have seen it. What we need is the output of your program. Pretty pictures, you can save the bandwidth.

Comment: Re "*It does not fail*", Actually, you don't check if it fails or not. Though I'm sure you're right. A (single) fork is extremely unlikely to fail.

Comment: Very good point, and thank you for trusting me haha. Output added @n.'pronouns'm

Comment: Re "*`printf("Fork failed");`*", hmm. This message can only be printed if `fork` succeeded. It will get printed if the *`execv`* fails.

Comment: `arg[0]` should be the program name and _not_ the first [data] argument. So, you want: `char *arg[4]` [one more]. And, you want: `arg[0] = "PipeW1"; arg[1] = fdNumberAsString; ...` Also, if `execv` returns, you may want: `execv("./PipeW1",arg);`

Comment: If the fork fails the printf and exit after it will be reached due to no program overwriting the current one, no? At least this is how I was taught to do it @ikegami

Comment: Finally, you are making contradictory claims. If `execv` failed, that means the program would have continued executing and `Fork failed`. But because that was printed, the program must have been executed. So which one is it? Did you get a message or did the program execute?

Comment: You don't need to pass the file descriptor [as an ascii string] to the child program. The more usual with `pipe` is to use `dup2` in the child _before_ the exec. (e.g.) `dup2(1,fd[1]); close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]); execv(...)` Then, the child program can just write to `stdout`. The parent can do `close(fd[1]);` and then `read(fd[0],buf,sizeof(buf))` in a loop to get the child data. Also, the parent should wait for process termination at the end (e.g.) `wait(NULL);`

Comment: Sorry, I confused fork and execv. I get no message whatsoever but none of the program's printfs appear in the console, added output to bottom of my op @ikegami

Comment: First thing first, try adding `\n` to all of your prints. Second, check return values of all functions you call (except those that print info messages) and print messages if any of them fail. `perror` is your friend.

Comment: Very good point about wait, added that. And regrettably I'm not permitted to use dup or dup2 here... @CraigEstey

Comment: Okay, no `dup/dup2`. IMO, that's, well ... _insane_ but ;-) Remember what I said about `arg[0]`. So, child program wants:  `fd[0] = atoi(args[1]); fd[1] = atoi(args[2]);`. In the child _process_ [before `execv`], skip the `dup2` but, you still need to close the read end of the pipe, so do: `close(fd[0]); execv(...);` Because you're _not_ doing `dup2`, you _may_ also need to _clear_ the "close on exec" flag for `fd[1]`. See: `man fcntl` to clear `FD_CLOEXEC` (e.g. `close(fd[0]); int flags = fcntl(fd[1],F_GETFL); fcntl(fd[1],F_SETFL,flags & ~FD_CLOEXEC); execv(...)`).

Comment: It is less insane than sadistic in this case lol, and did fix arg[0]! and curious- can I not close fd[0] in the child? prof seemed to think that better, but again, he also enjoys unironic torture @CraigEstey

Comment: To reconcile two POV: _A sadistic prof is insane and an insane prof is usually sadistic ..._ There ... We're in complete agreement :-)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, child should close `fd[0]`; It is the usual [safer] practice to close the [whichever] end of the pipe that the process (e.g. parent or child) is _not_ using. This is particularly important if doing a "create shell program that supports pipes" assignment. So, for a pipe that is: "child writes to parent", parent process should close `fd[1]` and child _process_ should close `fd[0]` (e.g.) `if (pid == 0) { close(fd[0]); fcntl ...; execv(...); } else { close(fd[1]); while (1) read(fd[0],...); close(fd[0]); wait(NULL); }`

Comment: That is the normal way to do it for an arbitrary child _program_. But, since you're controlling the child program, you _can_ have the child _program_ do the close of `fd[0]`, if you wish. But, 99.44% `[*]` of the time, it's the invoker that does the most setup, because it's in the best position to know the correct actions to take. `[*]` purity of Ivory Soap ...

Comment: Makes sense, thanks so much for your advice and wisdom, I really do appreciate it @CraigEstey